# Ruby Regex to match multiple portions of a string

Tags: ruby, regex

*Using Ruby: ruby 1.9.3dev (2011-09-23 revision 33323) [i686-linux]*

I have the following string:

```
str = 'Message relates to activity <a href="/activities/35">TU4 Sep 5 Activity 1</a> <img src="/images/layout/placeholder.png" width="222" height="149"/><br/><br/>First question from Manager on TU4 Sep 5 Activity 1.'
```

I want to match the following:

> 35 (a number which is part of href attribute value)
>   TU4 Sep 5 Activity (the text for  tag)
>   First question from Manager on TU4 Sep 5 Activity 1. (the remaining text after last `<br/><br/>` tags)

For achieving the same I have written the following regex

```
result = str.match(/<a href="\/activities\/(?<activity_id>\d+)">(?<activity_title>.*)<\/a>.*<br\/><br\/>(?<message>.*)/)
```

This produces following result:

```
#<MatchData "<a href=\"/activities/35\">TU4 Sep 5 Activity 1</a> <img src=\"/images/layout/placeholder.png\" width=\"222\" height=\"149\"/><br/><br/>First question from Manager on TU4 Sep 5 Activity 1." 
         activity_id:"35" 
         activity_title:"TU4 Sep 5 Activity 1" 
         message:"First question from Manager on TU4 Sep 5 Activity 1.">
```

But I guess this is not efficient.
Is it possible that somehow only the required values(as mentioned above under what I want to match) is returned in the matched result and the following
value gets excluded from matched result:

```
"<a href=\"/activities/35\">TU4 Sep 5 Activity 1</a> <img src=\"/images/layout/placeholder.png\" width=\"222\" height=\"149\"/><br/><br/>First question from Manager on TU4 Sep 5 Activity 1."
```

Thanks,

Jignesh

Comment: You should never attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions. This is almost guaranteed to fail. Use a proper (XML) parser instead. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/421705

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate way to do this is NOT to use regexen. Instead, use the Nokogiri library to easily parse your html:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(str)
activity_id = doc.css('[href^="/activities"]').attr('href').value[/\d+$/]
activity_title = doc.css('[href^="/activities"]')[0].inner_text
message = doc.search("//text()").last
```

This will do exactly what your regexp was attempting, with much lower chance of random failure.